# Change selected text content with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to edit selected text using content_sript.js in my chrome extension. The highlighted text should only cover one node in the html but I haven't figured out how to enforce that yet

This is the code in content_scripts.js
`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { if (request.action === "changeText") { console.log(window.getSelection().toString()); console.log(window.getSelection()); window.getSelection().deleteFromDocument(); const new_text = "Text i need to insert"; sendResponse({worked:true}); } });`
I have figured out how to delete the selected text but now I need to somehow insert the text back in.

Comment: You likely want to get the `document.activeElement` that contains the selected text, get it's text content, then do a replacement of the selected part with your new part between `.selectionStart` and `.selectionEnd`.